# Altium Designer 16: Baked symbols in schematic templates

Tags: altium

I have a small number of template projects, including project file, schematic file, PCB file and Array file. These were created in AD 14, updated to 15 and now 16.

The schematic contains a number of parts that have been dictated for use by our design standard, such as fiducials, template, badmark, BOM entry for PCB, etc. The PCB has the corresponding footprints for these components.

Since moving to AD16, the new project "bakes in" these parts to the template so they are basically pictures. This tricks the difference engine into believing they don't exist, and wipes the parts from the PCB.

Has anyone else experienced this, and is there a new way of making templates, or some setting for shutting off this behaviour?

Comment: Did you make contact with Altium support?

Comment: This is the first time I hear of this. I know it's not super helpful to you, but maybe it drives you to pick up @BenceKaulics 's suggestion. I have avidly used Altium (and some others) for several years as Freelancer, so it's not just another hobbyist trolling.

Comment: When you double-click on the items in the template, what window pops up (if any)?

Comment: If you are referring to a used template, as in a new schematic for a new project, then nothing. You can not click them, select them, move them, nothing. They are locked down, the same as the borders or title blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it has become apparent that a distinction is required between:

1. The *.SchDot file that is used as the drawing backdrop template, and
2. A *.SchDoc file that is used as part of a PROJECT template

The former "bakes in" everything as a permanent fixture, whilst the latter permits the inclusion of components as per any normal schematic.

The solution to my above issue was to remove all components from the *.SchDot file, and use it to contain only drawing objects, such as the title block.

Any components to be added to all boards as a matter of procedure were included in sample *.SchDoc files, as part of template projects.